# React not re-rendering when I update my redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I know it's me... Because I suck :)

But I believe I am doing everything correct but when I dispatch my action and the state changes my view does not re-render.

I believe this is the simple change that might be needed but the

**render()**

```
render(){
    ....
    <div className={data.participants}>
        +{store.getState().currentSex.participants}
    </div>
    ....
}
```

**Function that calls the action**

```
onSetParticipants = () => {
    console.info(store.getState()); //participants = 1
    store.dispatch (currentSex.setParticipants(3));
    console.info(store.getState()); //participants = 3
}
```

**reducer currentSex.js**

```
import { List, Map } from 'immutable';

const initialState = {
    participants: 1
};

function currentSex (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_PARTICIPANTS':
            return {
                ...state,
                participants:action.participants
            }
    }
    return state
}

export default currentSex;
```

**Actions**

```
export const SET_PARTICIPANTS = 'SET_PARTICIPANTS';

export function setParticipants(participants) {
    return {
        type: SET_PARTICIPANTS,
        participants: participants
    }
}
```

**How I have done my connect, as I believe this helps**

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        errorMessage: state.errorMessage,
        inputValue: ownProps.location.pathname.substring(1)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { })(App)
```

Please forgive me is this isn't enough or completely the wrong information.

But why does my page no re-render when i can see the state has changed?

**edit**

Its worth mentioning that my state has objects inside of it:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to import the actions and mapDispatchToProps to your connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `mapStateToProps` you need to add the state that you want to render inside your component. In this case it looks like `state.participants`.

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        errorMessage: state.errorMessage,
        participants: state.participants,
        inputValue: ownProps.location.pathname.substring(1)
    }
}
```

And then use `this.props.participants` in your component.

```
import * as actions from '../actions';

/* ... */

render(){
    ....
    <div className={data.participants}>
        +{this.props.participants}
    </div>
    ....
}

/* ... */

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App)
```

**edit**

And add the actions to your connect function, as well as importing them. Call your actions using `this.props.currentSex(3)` inside the function within your component that handles change events.

Comment: oh wow, you need a mapStateToProps in each view. I am only doing this once for the entire app. Inside my `App.js` I think I will need to read up more about why connect needs this. Thank you

Comment: So my question is, if its understandable. I have a root view, that everything goes through because I am using router-history. I wasn't aware this would make a difference. My state is a layered object. So I guess I just need to put references to that inside of the mapStateToProps with the parent of each state object ak: `auth, currentSex, routing` I believe?

Comment: Anywhere you are accessing state in the Redux store you have to map state to props and likewise anywhere you are accessing your action creators. It does make it easier to reason about the store, and accessing actions.

Comment: Yes your state in mapDispatchToProps matches the nesting level according to how you set up your store. Eg. In mapStateToProps you would have foo: state.bar.foo where bar matches the nesting.

Comment: Nice one Alexi :d and oh boy my stateToProps is about to get a whole lot bigger lol

Comment: I've also just noticed that you moved the participants into the components  props. This is just so it will refresh the view? Whilst the dispatcher will update the store right? Also why `props` and not use the local `state`?

Comment: Yes it ties the state that updates in your store to the value on props, which will re-render on changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122865/discussion-between-jamie-hutber-and-alexi2).

Comment: Nailed it, I had a few things that were out in when using mapDispatchToProps as well, but once I knew I was on the right track.